# Copy part of data to another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a populated pandas Dataframe and I'm trying to create another column and fill it with some characters from another column.

Example:

This is my dataframe **df1**

```
  a    b    c
 1234 4567 7890
 0987 7654 4321
 0708 7080 9080
```

Now I want to create a column called 'd' and fill with a part of the data from column 'a'.
The result would be:

```
   a    b    c    d
 1234 4567 7890  12
 0987 7654 4321  09
 0708 7080 9080  07
```

I want the first 2 characters from 'a'.

I've tried this:

```
df1['d'] = df1.apply(
    lambda row: pd.Series.str.split(pat=df1t['a'], n=2, expand=False),
    axis=1
)
```

But I received this error:

> TypeError: ("split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'",
>   'occurred at index 0')

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`str` subscript slice method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html):

```
df1['d'] = df1.a.str[: 2]

>>> df1.d
0    12
1    98
2    07
Name: d, dtype: object
```

Also, as a rule of thumb, try to avoid using `apply`, as it is as slow as molasses.

Answer (score 0):

from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def func(a):
    if a and len(str(a))>=2:
        return int(str(a)[:2])
    else:
        return None

func_udf = udf(func, IntegerType())
df1 = df2.withColumn('d',func_udf(df1['a']))

Comment: Why do you think this question is related to spark?